# Is there a code sample for multiple producers in spring kafka?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have an application that may need multiple producers. All code samples I see seem to support a single producer, reading config from app during app startup. If there are multiple producers and we want to pass in different producer config, is there out of the box support in Spring? Or should I just go without spring in that case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create several `Producer` instances (`KafkaTemplate`) via the same `ProducerFactory`.

If you need different Kafka configurations, you’ll need different `ProducerFactory` instances.

Answer (score 22):

you will have to create two different `ProducerFactory` below is example

```
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
    import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
    import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;

    import java.util.HashMap;

    @Configuration
    public class KafkaProducerConfig {


        @Bean
        public ProducerFactory<String, String> confluentProducerFactory() {

            HashMap<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            configProps.put(
                    ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                    "localhost:9092");
            configProps.put(
                    ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                    StringSerializer.class);
            configProps.put(
                    ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                    StringSerializer.class);
            return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
        }


        @Bean
        public ProducerFactory<String, String> cloudraProducerFactory() {

            HashMap<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            configProps.put(
                    ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                    "localhost:9094");
            configProps.put(
                    ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                    StringSerializer.class);
            configProps.put(
                    ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                    StringSerializer.class);
            return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
        }

        @Bean(name = "confluent")
        public KafkaTemplate<String, String> confluentKafkaTemplate() {
            return new KafkaTemplate<>(confluentProducerFactory());
        }

        @Bean(name = "cloudera")
        public KafkaTemplate<String, String> clouderaKafkaTemplate() {
            return new KafkaTemplate<>(cloudraProducerFactory());
        }

    }




public class ProducerExample {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("cloudera")
    private KafkaTemplate clouderaKafkaTemplate;


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("confluent")
    private KafkaTemplate confluentKafkaTemplate;

    public void send() {
        confluentKafkaTemplate.send("TestConfluent", "hey there..confluent");
        clouderaKafkaTemplate.send("TestCloudEra","hey there.. cloudera");
    }

}
```

Comment: and multiple consumer ?

Comment: Can different producer factories(ie producer kafka config) be defined in application properties?

Comment: @user518066 Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

If you still want to keep your configuration in `application.yaml` as usual, and keep Java configuration as minimum as possible, you can extend `KafkaProperties.Producer`.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.kafka.producer-1")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class FirstProducer extends KafkaProperties.Producer {
    private final KafkaProperties common;

    @Qualifier("producer-1")
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<?, ?> producerFactory() {
        final var conf = new HashMap<>(
            this.common.buildProducerProperties()
        );
        conf.putAll(this.buildProperties());
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(conf);

    }

    @Qualifier("producer-1")
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(this.producerFactory());

    }
}

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.kafka.producer-2")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class SecondProducer extends KafkaProperties.Producer {
    private final KafkaProperties common;

    @Qualifier("producer-2")
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<?, ?> producerFactory() {
        final var conf = new HashMap<>(
            this.common.buildProducerProperties()
        );
        conf.putAll(this.buildProperties());
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(conf);

    }

    @Qualifier("producer-2")
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(this.producerFactory());

    }
}
```

Comment: That looks nice! However, would there exist a way to do away with all of the boilerplate code? The only difference I can spot is the name of the properties prefix.

Comment: You can extract shared parts to a superclass, here code is duplicated just as an illustation

Answer (score 4):

Starting with version 2.5, you can use a RoutingKafkaTemplate to select the producer at runtime, based on the destination topic name.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#routing-template

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot doesn't provide out of the box support for multiple producer configuration. You can write your own custom kafka configuration to support multiple producer config something like this:-

```yaml
kafka:
  producer:
    producer1:
      topic: topic1
      bootstrap-servers: server1:9092,server1:9093,server1:9094
      retries: 0
      acks: all
    producer2:
      topic: topic2
      bootstrap-servers: server2:9092,server2:9093,server2:9094
      retries: 2
      acks: 1
    producer3:
      ...
    producer4:
      ...
```

Read the configuration from class file:-

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "kafka")
@Getter
@Setter
public class KafkaCustomProperties {
  private List<String> bootstrapServers = new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList("localhost:9092"));
  private String clientId;
  private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
  private Map<String, KafkaProperties.Producer> producer;
  private Map<String, KafkaProperties.Consumer> consumer;
  private KafkaProperties.Ssl ssl = new KafkaProperties.Ssl();
  private KafkaProperties.Security security = new KafkaProperties.Security();

  public Map<String, Object> buildCommonProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    if (this.bootstrapServers != null) {
      properties.put(CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.bootstrapServers);
    }
    if (this.clientId != null) {
      properties.put(CommonClientConfigs.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, this.clientId);
    }
    properties.putAll(this.ssl.buildProperties());
    properties.putAll(this.security.buildProperties());
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.properties)) {
      properties.putAll(this.properties);
    }
    return properties;
  }
}
```

use this configuration to generate `KafkaTemplate` beans for each producer using `@Qualifier` annotation

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class KafkaMultipleProducerConfig {

  private final KafkaCustomProperties kafkaCustomProperties;

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("producer1")
  public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> producer1KafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory("producer1"));
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("producer2")
  public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> producer2KafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory("producer2"));
  }

  private ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory(String producerName) {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>(kafkaCustomProperties.buildCommonProperties());
    if (nonNull(kafkaCustomProperties.getProducer())) {
      KafkaProperties.Producer producerProperties = kafkaCustomProperties.getProducer().get(producerName);
      if (nonNull(producerProperties)) {
        properties.putAll(producerProperties.buildProperties());
      }
    }
    log.info("Kafka Producer '{}' properties: {}", producerName, properties);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(properties);
  }
}
```

and use these `KafkaTemplate` beans to publish message to different producer config.

Refer to the post https://codingnconcepts.com/spring-boot/configure-multiple-kafka-producer/ for detailed explanation.