# Sharing Kafka producer between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Is it possible to have single instance of a Kafka producer shared between multiple threads to send messages to multiple topics? Is there any concurrency issue I might want to be aware of before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kafka Producer - By default supports Multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540425/kafka-producer-by-default-supports-multithreading)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [`KafkaProducer`](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html) documentation

> The producer is thread safe and sharing a single producer instance across threads will generally be faster than having multiple instances.

So yes, it's perfectly valid and even recommended to share a single producer between multiple threads.

Comment: If I am pushing data from database to Kafka Producer to two different topics, how to achieve sending messages from same database simultaneously to two different topics ?

Comment: by invoking send for two times i guess.